# Repetitive Java constructors (refactoring or generation)

Tags: java, refactoring, code-generation, documentation-generation

## Problematic

I've been making a library for a framework that I'm using in Java: I have hundreds of LOC used purely for providing many constructors to the users, but each time, with one less argument (because a default value can be used). That leads to a lot of repeated code, and a lot of repeated JavaDoc. And, most of all, a lot of maintenance whenever a little thing changes.

---

## Example of solution

I feel like there could exist some library out there, similar to Lombok, that would allow me to annotate the constructors in such a way that it would automatically generate the constructors and their associated JavaDoc. Something like:

```java
/** Some description. */
public class Example {    

    /** Alternate1 description. */
    public SomeObject alternate1;

    /** Alternate2 description. */
    public SomeOtherObject alternate2;

    /** Attribute1 description. */
    public int attribute1 = 1;

    /** Attribute2 description. */
    public int attribute2 = 2;

    @InjectClassDoc
    @InjectAttributesDoc
    public Example (@ConstructorRequiredVariant SomeObject obj,
            @ConstructorOrderedCascade int attribute1,
            @ConstructorOrderedCascade int attribute2) {
        doSomething();
    }

    @InjectClassDoc
    @InjectAttributesDoc
    public Example (@ConstructorRequiredVariant SomeOtherObject obj,
            @ConstructorOrderedCascade int attribute1,
            @ConstructorOrderedCascade int attribute2) {
        doSomething();
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

That would generate something like:

```java
/** Some description. */
public class Example {    

    /** Alternate1 description. */
    public SomeObject someObject;

    /** Alternate2 description. */
    public SomeOtherObject someOtherObject;

    /** Attribute1 description. */
    public int attribute1 = 1;

    /** Attribute2 description. */
    public int attribute2 = 2;

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate1 description.
     * @param attribute1 Attribute1 description.
     * @param attribute2 Attribute2 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeObject obj,
            final int attribute1,
            final int attribute2) {
        this(obj, attribute1);
        setAttribute2(attribute2);
    }

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate1 description.
     * @param attribute1 Attribute1 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeObject obj,
            final int attribute1) {
        this(obj);
        setAttribute1(attribute1);
    }

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate1 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeObject obj) {
        setSomeObject(obj);
        doSomething();
    }

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate2 description.
     * @param attribute1 Attribute1 description.
     * @param attribute2 Attribute2 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeOtherObject obj,
            final int attribute1,
            final int attribute2) {
        this(obj, attribute1);
        setAttribute2(attribute2);
    }

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate2 description.
     * @param attribute1 Attribute1 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeOtherObject obj,
            final int attribute1) {
        this(obj);
        setAttribute1(attribute1);
    }

    /**
     * Some description.
     * @param obj Alternate2 description.
     */
    public Example (final SomeOtherObject obj) {
        setSomeOtherObject(obj);
        doSomething();
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

---

## Real-world example of the problem

This is just to give you a better idea of where I'm coming from with all of this.

Here is an excerpt of the source of my problem ([link to the actual repo's source](https://github.com/payne911/PieMenu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/payne/games/piemenu/PieWidget.java#L56-L317)):

```java
/** Some description that is reused on all constructors seen by the users. */
public class PieWidget extends RadialGroup {

    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected void constructorsCommon(TextureRegion whitePixel) {
        this.whitePixel = whitePixel;
    }


    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel, float preferredRadius) {
        super(preferredRadius);
        constructorsCommon(whitePixel);
    }


    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                        float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent) {
        super(preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent);
        constructorsCommon(whitePixel);
    }


    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                        float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset) {
        super(preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset);
        constructorsCommon(whitePixel);
    }


    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                        float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent,
                        float startDegreesOffset, float totalDegreesDrawn) {
        super(preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset, totalDegreesDrawn);
        constructorsCommon(whitePixel);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param style defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     PieWidgetStyle style, float preferredRadius) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius);
        setStyle(style);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param style defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     PieWidgetStyle style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent);
        setStyle(style);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param style defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     PieWidgetStyle style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset);
        setStyle(style);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param style defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     * @param totalDegreesDrawn the {@link #totalDegreesDrawn} that defines how
     *                          many degrees the widget will span, starting from
     *                          its {@link #startDegreesOffset}.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     PieWidgetStyle style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset, float totalDegreesDrawn) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset, totalDegreesDrawn);
        setStyle(style);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, float preferredRadius) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius);
        setStyle(skin.get(PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent);
        setStyle(skin.get(PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset);
        setStyle(skin.get(PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     * @param totalDegreesDrawn the {@link #totalDegreesDrawn} that defines how
     *                          many degrees the widget will span, starting from
     *                          its {@link #startDegreesOffset}.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset, float totalDegreesDrawn) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset, totalDegreesDrawn);
        setStyle(skin.get(PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param style the name of the style to be extracted from the skin.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, String style, float preferredRadius) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius);
        setStyle(skin.get(style, PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }




    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param style the name of the style to be extracted from the skin.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, String style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent);
        setStyle(skin.get(style, PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param style the name of the style to be extracted from the skin.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, String style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset);
        setStyle(skin.get(style, PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }


    /**
     * See {@link PieWidget} for a description.
     *
     * @param whitePixel a 1x1 white pixel.
     * @param skin defines the way the widget looks like.
     * @param style the name of the style to be extracted from the skin.
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     * @param totalDegreesDrawn the {@link #totalDegreesDrawn} that defines how
     *                          many degrees the widget will span, starting from
     *                          its {@link #startDegreesOffset}.
     */
    public PieWidget(final TextureRegion whitePixel,
                     Skin skin, String style, float preferredRadius,
                     float innerRadiusPercent, float startDegreesOffset, float totalDegreesDrawn) {
        this(whitePixel, preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset, totalDegreesDrawn);
        setStyle(skin.get(style, PieWidgetStyle.class));
    }

    // ... then the actual methods start
}
```

The parent class:

```java
public class RadialGroup extends WidgetGroup {

    /** Used internally for the shared properties among constructors of RadialWidgets. */
    protected void constructorsCommon() {
        setTouchable(Touchable.childrenOnly);
    }


    /**
     * See {@link RadialGroup} for a description.
     *
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     */
    public RadialGroup(float preferredRadius) {
        setPreferredRadius(preferredRadius);
        constructorsCommon();
    }

    /**
     * See {@link RadialGroup} for a description.
     *
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     */
    public RadialGroup(float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent) {
        this(preferredRadius);
        setInnerRadiusPercent(innerRadiusPercent);
    }

    /**
     * See {@link RadialGroup} for a description.
     *
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     */
    public RadialGroup(float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent,
                       float startDegreesOffset) {
        this(preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent);
        setStartDegreesOffset(startDegreesOffset);
    }

    /**
     * See {@link RadialGroup} for a description.
     *
     * @param preferredRadius the {@link #preferredRadius} that defines the 
     *                        size of the widget.
     * @param innerRadiusPercent the {@link #innerRadiusPercent} that defines
     *                           the percentage of the radius that is cut off,
     *                           starting from the center of the widget.
     * @param startDegreesOffset the {@link #startDegreesOffset} that defines
     *                           how far from the origin the drawing begins.
     * @param totalDegreesDrawn the {@link #totalDegreesDrawn} that defines how
     *                          many degrees the widget will span, starting from
     *                          its {@link #startDegreesOffset}.
     */
    public RadialGroup(float preferredRadius, float innerRadiusPercent,
                       float startDegreesOffset, float totalDegreesDrawn) {
        this(preferredRadius, innerRadiusPercent, startDegreesOffset);
        setTotalDegreesDrawn(totalDegreesDrawn);
    }

    // ...
}
```

The structure is rather simple:

- there is a `constructorsCommon()` method used to do common operations for any constructor used.
- the constructors themselves are quite trivial too: they use the `setter` associated with a single field of the class, and then pass the call to the other constructor which had one less attribute defined.
- there are 3 sets of constructors for the class: one for each different way of providing a Skin to instantiate the class, and each of those is replicated 4 times (one for each of the common attributes that can be set for all of those 3 methods).

I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce that amount of copy-pasted code and documentation out there. Ideally, I would end up with only 3 constructors, instead of 12.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid writing exponentially many constructors when a class has several optional fields with default values, you can use the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). For example:

```java
public class Example {
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private char c;
    private boolean d;

    private Example(int a, String b, char c, boolean d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        // required fields
        private int a;
        private String b;

        // optional fields with default values
        private char c = 'c';
        private boolean d = false;

        public Builder(int a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public Builder c(char c) {
            this.c = c;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder d(boolean d) {
            this.d = d;
            return this;
        }

        public Example build() {
            return new Example(a, b, c, d);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like `new Example.Builder(23, "foo").c('y').d(false).build()` to create a new object with every field given an initial value, or omit some of the chained methods to use the default values for those fields.

Comment: Somehow, I hadn't considered the Builder pattern as a solution, but it is indeed a good idea. However, it would change the way people interact with the library and bump the version up (because it'd be a non-backward-compatible change), which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I see. Personally, I would implement the Builder pattern but leave the existing public constructors and mark them as deprecated, with Javadoc saying to use the Builder class(es) instead. I'd rather not commit to maintaining and documenting so many similar constructors in the long-term. But I understand why you might choose otherwise.